# On hover not working properly on Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I trying to change the color of by background  on android:state_hovered.But it is not reflecting any changes on my application.Now what i want to when the relative layout get focused i want to change it's background and the that time i want to change the color of my Text View Text .But this code is not working for me please suggest me the changes 
this is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_demo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flight_relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flight_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flight_arrow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:text="@string/flight_tittle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content_flight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/flight_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flight_arrow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_list_image"
            android:text="@string/flight_content"
            android:textColor="#2f2f2f"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flight_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/flight_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my style file that is button_effect.xml to change the background of my relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_hovered="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_bg"></item>
    </selector>
```

This is my text_color.xml to change the color of the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#177f75"/>
   <item android:color="#152b72"/>
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, for `textview` as well as with your `layout`.

Here I have used `drawables` for different state when - pressed, hovered and normal.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/book_press" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/book_focused" android:state_focused="true"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/book_default"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Instead of `drawables` use your color. Hope this will help you.

And you can set layout focused using xml for using Java code.

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: @Rahul What all this you have done? Can you show us. Do one more thing, make `android:background="@drawable/yourhoverxml"`. Have you tried this one?

Comment: i have done that     code is here   for calling <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flight_relative"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="myFancyMethod"
        android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

Comment: What is happening right now? Can you explain. You want to have effect when someone taps on the layout or hover above it. Right?

Answer (score 0):

use this for changing text color on hover

```
 textview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //Button Pressed
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                 //finger was lifted
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```