# How to create a form that have autolookup in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use auto look up for searching .
I have partially created this layout . This is my XML code.
Now how can i use autol lookup in this?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_demo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flight_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roundtripTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:text="Round trip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OneWayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:text="OneWay"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multicityTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:text="MultiCity"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/from2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fromTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:text="From" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
    android:text="To" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i have to use a auto look up box same below to the to i have to use autolook up and in the middle of both there will be image .So i have done till from and to part now i am not able to create to separate auto look up box below from and to.

Comment: What do you think my friend, are we here for complete your project? Why do you have every time layout problem? You don't want to try anything your self. Sorry, but you should try your self. We are here to help you in error or code part. Every day you have new layout and you are asking for creating layout from us!!! Very Bad my friend.

Comment: @ChintanRathod I completely agree with u...we are not here to complete anybodies project

Comment: @Rahul, I am not opposing anything, but until you give some effort, I can not help you. I have posted layout which may help you to solve your problem. Hope you don't take me wrongly. My intention is not to demotivate you.

Comment: @ChintanRathod i am very much thank full to u that u have showed me something .because of that i have done something more and i have given my full efforts today.I know bro u r intentions thanks alot

Comment: @ChintanRathod i am facing some layout issue will help me in that ..???

Comment: @Rahul, Ya sure.. what kind of help do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roundtripTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Round trip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OneWayTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="OneWay"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multicityTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0000FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MultiCity"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fromTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="From" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="LON"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="London Great Britain"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/toTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="To" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="DXB"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Dubai United Arab Emirates"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**

Put below layout after "from/to" layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="LON" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="DXB" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have to use auto look up for the from and to .So what i have to use get the auto look below the from and to layout

Comment: Just change `EditText` to `AutoCompleteTextView`. This will be fine.

Comment: i think u didn't got mt problem @chintan

Comment: @Rahul, Please briefly explain what do you want to do?

Comment: as i have updated my XMLcode please see it for the reference.The as is image i have posted below to the from part i have to use a auto look up box same below to the to i have to use autolook up and in the middle of both there will be image .So i have done till from and to part now i am not able to create to separate auto look up box below from and to .Use my code and  edit it.thanks

Comment: But layout which i have posted will do such thing. You just need to replace both edittext and to add some list of predefined countries to the AutoCompleteTextView. When you type something, it will automatically fill the text.

Comment: brother for from and to i have already used a linear layout and i have to use a image as it's background .in that i have use textview to set from and to text now below that i have to create a layout that have 3 thing from and to autocomplete text box and in middle of them a image and i have to use two images in the middle of from and to

Comment: can you roughly sketch a layout? with text. Where and how you want views at which place. I am not getting in your words. :(

Comment: http://s13.postimg.org/h3vl5mybb/Capture.png this link red part i have create as a autoo look up box on both side and two images in between them.So for from and to have already create a layout with it's background now below that i have to create this auto box and image

Comment: have u got what i am trying to do